# How to make Leaflet polylines more 'touchable' or tap-friendly?

Tags: leaflet, maps, touch, gis, react-leaflet

I'm rendering GEOJSON using leaflet, including a variety of linestrings. For whatever reason, I can seldom get the touch events to work. As in, it's very hard to have the fingers actually target the right spot on the screen.

Here's my map:

```
return (
        <Map
            style={{
                height: '100%',
                width: '100%',
                margin: '0 auto'
            }}
            onClick={this.closeAllMapPopups}
            ref={(el) => {
                this.leafletMap = el;
            }}
            center={position}
            zoom={9}>
            <TileLayer url='https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.outdoors/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYawefawelbnMyNCIsImawefbDRtMzcwMDNmMzJydHdvcjF6ODA5In0.xdZi4pmkhj1zb9Krr64CXw' attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/">Mapbox</a>' />
            <GeoJSON data={locations} ref="geojson" style={this.getStyle} onEachFeature={this.onEachFeature} 

            />{' '}
        </Map>
```

Here's my onEachFeature:

```
onEachFeature = (feature, layer) => {
        //console.log(layer);

        layer.on({
            mouseover: (e) => this.MouseOverFeature(e, feature),
            click: (e) => this.clickFeature(e, feature),
            mouseout: (e) => this.resetHighlight(e, feature),


        });
    };
```

The touch events (click = tap) only seem to work when I get lucky. How does one make leaflet polylines more clickable?

Explored the plugin options but most are outdated:
https://github.com/geoloep/Leaflet.ClickTolerance
https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-touch-helper/

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`tolerance` option of `L.Renderer`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#renderer-tolerance) (i.e. use a `tolerance` option when instantiating a [`L.Canvas`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#canvas) or a [`L.SVG`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#svg) renderer). The value for that option is given in pixels.

e.g. take the [example code in the Leaflet documentation for `L.Canvas`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#canvas) and include a `tolerance`:

```
var map = L.map('map');
var myRenderer = L.canvas({ padding: 0.5, tolerance: 20 });
var line = L.polyline( coordinates, { renderer: myRenderer } );
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not allowed to comment, so I will create a new answer.

You can only use `tolerance` with `Canvas` renderer, as you might saw by playing around.

The answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54616877/6655713) is a good starting point but needed clarification on this one.

There is also an issue at [github](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/7494)